# [matplotlib]: write dates on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here an example code in which I would like to draw the entire date on the x axis

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

years = np.arange( 2005, 2016, 1)
years[1] = 2005
years[2] = 2005
months = [ 3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 12, 2, 3, 5, 2, 6]
dates = []
for Y in years:
    dates = dates + [ datetime.datetime(Y, 6 , 4) ]


y = np.random.randn(len(dates))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot_date(dates, y, 'r+', ms = 2, mew = 12)

ax.fmt_xdata = DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d')
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately the result is this
[image]

And what I need is to write all the date on the x axis like in this picture

[image]

What you suggest me to change on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.fmt_xdata` is the formatter for the dates usually only used for the hover functionality in interactive plots. [image]

What you want here is to set the major formatter of the xaxis to a `DateFormatter`:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%b-%d-%Y'))
```

[image]